# $E[X|X^3-3X]=0$

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Prove that $E[X|X^3-3X]=0$, with $f(x)=\frac{|x^2-1|}{4}$ being the density function of $X$ in the interval $[-2,2]$.

My attempt:

Let $Y=X^3-3X$ and $x_1, x_2, x_3$  the roots of $x^3-3x=y$.
\begin{gather*}
P_{X\circ Y}(A\times B)=P_\Omega(X\in A\cap Y\in B)=\int_{y\in B}I_A(x)f(x)dx=\\
=\int_B\sum_{i=1}^3I_A(x_i)f(x_i)/|3x_i^2-3|dy=\int_B\frac{\sum I_A(x_i)f(x_i)/|3x_i^2-3|}{\sum f(x_i)/|3x_i^2-3|}dP_Y 
\end{gather*}
From where:
$$P_{X/Y}(y)(A)=P_\Omega[X\in A|Y=y]=\frac{1}{3}\sum I_A(x_i)$$
Therefore:
$$E[X|Y=y]=\frac{1}{3}\sum x_i=0$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: Start with the definition of the [conditional expectation of a continuous random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Continuous_random_variables) and work back to what you know.

Comment: @Galen Meta-hint: there's a much simpler solution requiring no calculation at all.

Comment: @whuber I am not suggesting calculation. I am suggesting going back to definitions. Often when I cannot solve a problem like this it is because I have not paid enough attention to the elementary definitions or results. 

Comment: @Galen Fair enough -- but applying the definition devolves to computing something.  And even a definition isn't needed here: merely the truly basic idea that the conditional expectation is a property of the joint distribution alone, not of the random variables.

Comment: @whuber You're right, a rote calculation is the most natural thing to take away from the definition alone. My phrasing could have been better to help the OP avoid that less efficient/concise approach.

Definitions will be needed. What is a joint distribution, for example? It is an elementary notion in statistics, but if the OP doesn't know it then there's no time like present to learn it. 

Comment: OP: What I am suggesting is analogous to [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). That is, start with what you think is the target concept / problem and work backward until you can understand / solve it. This approach has worked exceptionally well for me. With standard mathematics, almost everything is eventually decomposable to elementary notions of "collection" and something like ["laws of thought"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought) (although once you hit philosophy almost everything seems up for debate...). [to be continued...]

Comment: [...] Hopefully you don't need to go that far back, but go as far as you need to. Even if your initial target is a miss, it will likely inform your choice for the next target.